# bash script error stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect, here-document

I'm using here-documents in a bash script to automate installation and setup where a password is required many times. I enter the password once and the script passes it to the various commands. In most instances the here-document approach handles this fine. However, in one case I get this error:

```
Enter VNC password: stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Verify password:    
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Please notice that this error message is from `x11vnc -storepassword` (not from `sudo`.)

My problem is related to `x11vnc -storepasswd` and here's my code:

```
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd << ENDDOC
password
password
y
ENDDOC
```

That obviously (from the error) does not work. I would appreciate a working example of how to implement `sudo x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd` in a script.

In case it helps, the prompts look like this:

> Enter VNC password:
>   Verify password:
>   Write password to /home/user/.vnc/passwd? [y]/n n

Will using `expect` be a better solution? If so, how would I use it in this case? (I have never used `expect` before but I have looked at a lot of examples since posting this question and I cannot get `expect` to work on my own.)

Comment: I have a related error but don't understand the actual error msg: `Password for brando9: stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device`, what does it mean?

Comment: what is `expect`?

Comment: this is a good related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Comment: related but nothing works here https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password I wish I could use ssh which I do have. I don't have sudo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x11vnc` expects its standard input to be a terminal, and it changes the terminal mode to avoid echoing the password as you're typing. When standard input isn't a terminal, the [`stty`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stty) calls to turn echo off and back on fail, hence the warning that you see.

Expect is indeed a solution. Try this script (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd
expect "password:" {send "swordfish" "\r"}
expect "password:" {send "swordfish" "\r"}
expect "Write*\?" {send "y\r"}
```

Alternatively, if you can, use an authentication method other than RFB (`-passwdfile`, or an SSL client certificate).

Comment: Thanks. However, the error is not coming from `sudo` it is coming from `x11vnc -storepassword`. I've been trying various `expect` approaches and I can't seem to get it right. An example using `expect` to enter a password for `x11vnc -storepassword` would be greatly appreciated. I'll update my question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @MountainX Right, sorry, I'd misread the question. Here's an expect script (completely untested).

Comment: Thank you. Your untested script gave me a few additional clues, but ultimately it also does not run without errors. The error is simply `Enter VNC password: usage: send [args] string` on the line `expect "password:" {send "swordfish" "\r"}`. I'm not sure how to fix that. Expect seems to be a very picky tool because I've been fooling with this particular problem for hours without working results yet.

Comment: The error (above comment) was coming from `send "swordfish" "\r"` and it was resolved by `send "swordfish\r"`. However, the solution still doesn't work. No password is written to ~/.vnc/passwd. I am still clueless as to why. As I said, I've been seeing this result in spite of trying everything I can think of so far.

Comment: BTW, the same commands used in your `expect` solution work when entered manually. They do not work in this `expect` script or any variation of it that I have tried so far.

Comment: I am getting following error: `spawn: command not found,  line 3: expect: command not found` should I put it into `.zshrc` file?

Comment: @alper This an an expect script, not a shell script. You need to write the code to a file, make it executable, and execute it. And you need to install `expect`.

Comment: I have a related error but don't understand the actual error msg: `Password for brando9: stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device`, what does it mean?

Comment: @CharlieParker Programs that want to read a password usually set the terminal in non-echo mode. If the standard input is not a terminal, they try and fail. An “ioctl” is an instruction to do something on a device other than read and write. Only terminals support the “turn off echo’ ioctl, not regular files or pipes.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' so how do I let the command accept my password? This `echo $SU_PASSWORD | /afs/cs/software/bin/reauth` used to work but idk what change when I last ran that command. It only let's me type it manually as a human :/

Comment: @CharlieParker Ask this as a question. (And I personally wouldn't know, I'm not familiar with this `reauth` command (is that a standard thing of AFS? If not you'll need to explain where it's from).)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' sure I will. One quick question while I do that. How do you set the terminal into "echo mode"? (addressing Programs that want to read a password usually set the terminal in non-echo mode. suggestion/comment).

Comment: @CharlieParker Also, since you've found this answer, I assume you've tried to adapt the expect script and failed. Include your attempt in your question and the error messages.

Comment: @CharlieParker Echo mode is the default. You can use `stty -echo` or `stty echo` to toggle it. But that won't help you here. The program wants to talk to the terminal.

Comment: why won't `stty echo` won't help me here? (btw, very grateful for your responses)

Comment: I'm trying to attempt your suggested solution but when I man the `spawn` and `expect` command in my (interactive) terminal the man page says there is no entry for those commands. I'm puzzled, why is that happening? I think perhaps just a little more details in your answer would help, cuz I'm not sure what your script is concretely doing (though I expect conceptually it's finding a way to send the password to a command so that "it works" regardless if one is a tty).

Comment: ok I think the expect solution won't work because the HPC server I have doesn't let me apt install it or run sudo. So I will try your other ssh solution you suggested though I'm not sure how to start but I will try.

Answer (score 7):

Another option to avoid those warning messages is to execute `x11vnc` in a pseudo-terminal created by a UNIX command (see [Using pseudo-terminals (pty) to control interactive programs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200106010404/https://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html)). This can be done with the `script` command or tools such as `pdip` ("Programmed Dialogue with Interactive Programs").

The warning messages on Mac OS X 10.6.8 for not providing a pseudo-terminal for `x11vnc`:

```
# x11vnc 0.9.14
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd << ENDDOC
password
password
y
ENDDOC

# Enter VNC password: stty: stdin isn't a terminal
#
# Verify password:    
# stty: stdin isn't a terminal
# Write password to ~/.vnc/passwd?  [y]/n Password written to: ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Solutions using the `script` command:

```
# GNU script command
sudo script -q -c 'x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd' <<ENDDOC /dev/null
password
password
y
ENDDOC

# ... or ...
printf '%s\n' 'password' 'password' 'y' | 
   sudo script -q -c 'x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd' /dev/null


# FreeBSD script command
sudo script -q /dev/null x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd <<ENDDOC
password
password
y
ENDDOC
```

Comment: I have a related error but don't understand the actual error msg: `Password for brando9: stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device`, what does it mean?

Comment: I can't use sudo :(

Answer (score 1):

Sudo has an option `-S` that allows it to read the passwd from STDIN.

```
[user@evil ~]$ tail -1 /etc/shadow
tail: cannot open `/etc/shadow' for reading: Permission denied
[user@evil ~]$ echo 'P@ssW3rd!' | sudo -S tail -1 /etc/shadow
nfsnobody:!!:15891::::::
```

Here is an example script to demonstrate the process:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hr {
    perl -e 'print "-" x 80, "\n";'
}

hr
read -p "Please enter your sudo password: " -s sudopasswd
echo

hr
echo "-sudo run: tail -1 /etc/shadow"
tail -1 /etc/shadow

hr
echo "+sudo run: tail -1 /etc/shadow"
echo "$sudopasswd" | sudo -S tail -1 /etc/shadow

hr
echo "-sudo run: ls -la /root/"
ls -la /root/

hr
echo "+sudo run: ls -la /root/"
echo "$sudopasswd" | sudo -S ls -la /root/

hr
```

Your script, would simply need to do something like:

```
read -p "Please enter your sudo password: " -s sudopasswd
echo "$sudopasswd" | sudo -S x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd
```

This would allow you to use sudo commands in your script without having to hardcode a password.

Alternatively, you could add your user, or a subset of users, the capability to run x11vnc with sudo, without a password, but adding a line like this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/x11vnc
```

Or create a `vncusers` group, add users to that group, and add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%vncusers    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/x11vnc
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the error is not coming from `sudo` it is coming from `x11vnc -storepassword`.